# RangePicker antd don't working set defaultValue

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use defaultValue in RangePicker - antd 5x

So error: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DAPR.png)

`<RangePicker defaultValue={[dayjs('2015/01/01', dateFormat), dayjs('2015/01/01', dateFormat)]} format={dateFormat} />`

Comment: What's the value of dateFormat?